# Returning a Collection's Slice type

Tags: swift, collections, slice

I'm trying to write a function that returns a `Collection` `Slice`, for the first occurrence of a given subsequence.

I've managed to write it as an `Array` extension, since I know that the return type would be `ArraySlice<Element>`, but I'm having trouble figuring out what the appropriate concrete output would be to make it a general function for `Collection`

```
extension Array where Element: Comparable {

    func firstOccuranceOf(subsequence: [Element]) -> ArraySlice<Element>? {

        guard !subsequence.isEmpty else {
            return nil
        }

        guard let startIndex = self.firstIndexOf(subsequence: subsequence) else {
            return nil
        }
        let endIndex = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: subsequence.count - 1)
        return self[startIndex...endIndex]
    }
}
```

TL;DR: How do I re-write the function above as a `extension Collection`?

Comment:  in mind that Collections may not be ordered

Comment: @XmasRights Are you looking for the whole `subsequence` to be a subset of the Array? or just its first element?

Comment: @Carpsen90 The slice returned should be a window to the whole subsequence

Comment: As you've defined it for Array, only the first element should be part of the original array. So that definition of `firstOccuranceOf(subsequence:)` has to be fixed first

Comment: @Carpsen90 My implementation of `firstIndexOf(subsequence:)` was not included, but it does indeed only return an index value if the entire subsequence is found. (it essentially iterates through the array calling `starts(with:)`)

Comment: What should `Array(1...10).firstOccurence(of: [6, 300])` according to the initial definition? As defined it would return `[6, 7]` not `nil`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to declare the return type as `Self.SubSequence?`. You'll also need to define the `firstIndex(of:)` method for `Collection`s that you use in your `Array` extension. I've defined it just to be able to compile the code, but feel free to change the implementation if your logic was different.

```
extension Collection where Element: Comparable {
    func firstIndex(of subsequence: Self) -> Index? {
        guard let firstElement = subsequence.first else { return nil }
        return self.firstIndex(of: firstElement)
    }

    func firstOccurence(of subsequence: Self) -> Self.SubSequence? {
        guard !subsequence.isEmpty else { return nil }
        guard let startIndex = firstIndex(of: subsequence) else { return nil }
        let endIndex = index(startIndex, offsetBy: subsequence.count - 1)
        return self[startIndex...endIndex]
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this even means `Array(1...10).firstOccurence(of: [6, 300,])`? Anyway, you should make sure you `endIndex` doesn't exceed `self.endIndex`

Comment: `Array(1...10).firstOccurence(of: [6, 300])` would return `nil`. `Array(1...10).firstOccurance(of: [2, 3])` would return an ArraySlice, which points to the first occurrence of a matching sequence. Right now, the purpose is to verify an occurrence exists, and inspect the start and end indexes

Comment: @XmasRights according to this answer it would return `[6, 7]`

Comment: @Carpsen90 as I've stated in my answer, the implementation of the `firstIndex(of:)` function might need to be changed to match the requirements of OP, since they weren't stated in the question. However, the question wasn't about the logic at all, it was about how to modify the existing function to work on `Collection`s. I only included the `firstIndex(of:)` function to be able to compile the code.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's fix `firstOccuranceOf(subsequence:)` as defined on `Array`:

```
//Only `Equatable` is needed
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    func firstOccurence(of subsequence: [Element]) -> ArraySlice<Element>? {
        let subsequenceEndIndex = subsequence.endIndex.advanced(by: -1)
        let lastPossibleFirstIndex = endIndex.advanced(by: -subsequenceEndIndex)

        for i in indices where i < lastPossibleFirstIndex {
            let range = i...i.advanced(by: subsequenceEndIndex)
            if Array(self[range]) == subsequence {
                return self[range]
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

It gives:

```
Array(1...10).firstOccurence(of: [6, 300])  //nil
Array(1...10).firstOccurence(of: [6, 7])    //[6, 7]
Array(1...6).firstOccurence(of: [6, 7])     //nil

let array: [Int] = []
array.firstOccurence(of: [6, 7])            //nil
array.firstOccurence(of: [])                //nil
```

---

For collections in general:

```
extension Collection where Self: RandomAccessCollection, Element: Equatable {
    func firstOccurence(of subsequence: Self) -> Self.SubSequence? {
        let subCount = subsequence.count
        for i in indices where distance(from: i, to: endIndex) >= subCount  {
            let subseq = self.suffix(distance(from: i, to: endIndex)).prefix(subCount)
            if Array(subseq) == Array(subsequence) {
                return subseq
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```